# Add view more in table React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a situation in which I have `complete data` on `frontend` like `50 records`.

I have to show the records in `Table`.

One time I can only `show 10` records. Then I have the `view more` button. `click` view more`. It will load the next` 10 records` and so on...

Can I get some help to solve this problem?

Table Code:-
4 components
`TableWrapper` `TableBody` TableHead `TableRow`

TableWrapper.js

```
const TableWrapper = ({...props}) => {
  const { tableData, columns } = props;
  const addNewRows = () => {
   console.log("Code for adding extra rows");
  }
  return (
    <table>
      <TableHead headers={columns} />
      <TableBody rows={tableData} tableData={tableData} headers={columns} />
    </table>
    <fragment onClick=addNewRows>View more</fragment>
  );
};

export default TableWrapper;
```

TableBody.js

```
const TableBody = ({...props}) => {
  const { rows, tableData, headers } = props;

  const [columnHeaderKeys, setColumnHeaderKeys] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    let keysArray = [];
    headers.map((headKeys) =>{
      keysArray.push(headKeys.field)
    })
    {keysArray.length !== 0 ? setColumnHeaderKeys(keysArray) : setColumnHeaderKeys([])}
  },[])

  return (
    <>
    {tableData.length !== 0 ?
      tableData.data.firstResponse.map((row, index)=>{
        return (<tr key={index}><TableRow key={index} data={row} keys={columnHeaderKeys}/></tr>)
      }) : <div>{"No Data is there"}</div>
    }
    </>
  );
};

export default TableBody;
```

TableHead.js

```
const TableHead = ({...props}) => {
  const { headers } = props;
  return (
    <>
        {headers.map(header => (
          <th
            key={`table-header-${header.key}`}
            style={header.style}>
            {header.header}
          </th>
        ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default TableHead;
```

TableRow.js

```
const TableRow = ({...props}) => {
  const { keys, data } = props;

  return (
    <>
    {keys.map((key)=>{
        return <td key={props.data[key]}>{props.data[key]}</td>
    })}
    </>
  );
};

export default TableRow;
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is it true that `tableData` has 50 records?  So you just want the first 10, then after clicking "more", 20, and clicking again gives you 30 etc?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `tableData` has all the rows (50 records), you
can keep track of how many records you're supposed to show with the `useState` hook.  Then simply pull out the rows you want based on that
value and hand it down to the table.

Something like this:

```
const PAGE_SIZE = 10;

const TableWrapper = ({...props}) => {
  const { tableData, columns } = props;

  const [ numToDisplay, setNumToDisplay ] = useState(PAGE_SIZE);
  
  const addNewRows = () => {
    console.log("Code for adding extra rows");
    let newCount = numToDisplay + PAGE_SIZE;
    if (numToDisplay > tableData.length) {
      newCount = tableData.length;
    }
    setNumToDisplay(newCount)
  }

  const visibleData = tableData.slice(0, numToDisplay);
  
  return (
    <table>
    <TableHead headers={columns} />
    <TableBody tableData={visibleData} headers={columns} />
    </table>
    <fragment onClick=addNewRows>View more</fragment>
  );
};
```

I also don't think you'll need the `rows` prop on `TableBody` because the `tableData` is the same as `rows` (from what I can tell from your description).